# Glass mapper Render Image data attributes

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

I'm trying to render a image field with RenderImage. I need some data- attributes in the image but I can't seem to figure out how to go about implementing that. I've tried this but doesn't work

```
@RenderImage(image, x => x.Image, new RenderingParameters("data-protect=true"), isEditable: true)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
@RenderImage(image, x => x.Image, new ImageParameters { Width = 100}, isEditable: true)
```

As of recent version of Glass - the only possible solution is

```
@RenderImage(image, x => x.Image, new { Width = 100}, isEditable: true)
```

Also you can take a look at - [TUTORIAL 16 - RENDERING IMAGES](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial16)

Comment: I've edited my question. The data-protect is a custom attribute. How can I get that to show up?

Comment: @Gabbar I don`t think it is possible without creating a new class than extends from AbstractParameters. You can check the default ImageParameters here. Just implement your custom class with the data required. https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/RenderField/ImageParameters.cs. Another option is to render the image manually (using the src property) and show it as editable only when in page editor mode.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'll try both approaches.

Answer (score 9):

Although the answer above will work I am going to be removing ImageParameters support in the future and moving to just anonymous type support:

```
@RenderImage(image, x => x.Image, new { Width = 100}, isEditable: true)
```

The reason for this change is because having a strongly type class like ImageParameters is very limiting. Anonymous types are also a common way of doing this with other frameworks so it would fit with what everyone else is doing.

Updated to include rendering of data attributes:

```
@RenderImage(image, x => x.Image, new { data_protect = "true"}, isEditable: true)
```

Comment: The issue was with data-protect that I haven't been able to get to work. So if you can add support for hyphen named attributes would be great.

Comment: Gabbar - the latest nightly release has this resolved. You can use "data_id" to get "data-id" in the same way as MVC.